# Javascript array which contains arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have two Javascript arrays which have been populated by a forloop.

I now want to assign both of those arrays to a new array. However, the two arrays are being called within another function. So, I want to assign the function, containing the two arrays to a new array.

The idea is to use a while loop to populate the new array with the two existing arrays.

The difficulty is that the browser does not seem to like assigning an array to the google.maps function: eg: `myarray[i] =  (google.maps.LatLng(array1[i],array2[i]))`

Here is the whole code... the actual bit that is going wrong is contained within the while loop toward the end of the code (the rest of it before the while loop works fine).

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($marker_result)) {

     $marker_location[] = $row["location"];
     $marker_lat[] = $row["lat"];
    $marker_lng[] = $row["lng"];

} //End of while loop

?>

<script>

//Converting php marker arrays to javascript marker arrays for use in for loop
     var js_markerloc_array= <?php echo json_encode($marker_location ); ?>;
    var js_markerlat_array= <?php echo json_encode($marker_lat ); ?>;
    var js_markerlng_array= <?php echo json_encode($marker_lng ); ?>;
    var markerloc_array = new Array(js_markerloc_array.length);
    var markerlat_array = new Array(js_markerloc_array.length);
    var markerlng_array = new Array(js_markerloc_array.length);

    for(var i=0; i<js_markerloc_array.length; i++){
            var jsloc = js_markerloc_array[i];
        var jslat = js_markerlat_array[i];
        var jslng = js_markerlng_array[i];
        markerloc_array[i] = jsloc;
        markerlat_array[i] = jslat;
        markerlng_array[i] = jslng;

}


// Now need to write all of this below into an array so that it can populate markers     from it! The difficulty is that the browser does not seem to like assigning the     google.maps.LatLng(array1[i],array2[i]) to a new array
//var mapmarker_array = new Array(js_markerloc_array.length);

i = 0;


while (i < js_markerloc_array.length)
{
    var mapmarker_array = new (google.maps.LatLng(markerlat_array[i],     markerlng_array[i])); //Uses coordinates from database "markers" table
    var test_marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position:mapmarker1, title:     markerloc_array[i]});
    document.write(mapmarker1);
    document.write(markerloc_array[i]);

i++;
}
```

Comment: your forloop at the top seems kinda pointless. you have three arrays, which you loop over, creating three more arrays that are identical to the first three... What's wrong with just using the three original arrays?

Comment: Most of your JS seems pointless. you build arrays in PHP and embed them into the JS with json_encode, you then loop over those arrays and copy their contents to OTHER arrays, and then you loop on those new arrays and try doing the google stuff. What's the point of all the array fiddling? You could just generate the appropriate array names to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I am Honestly not surprised this is not working.
Using `new Array(x)` can always behave unexpectedly.

It is much better to always use `[]` to create an array in Javascript. The top half of your script should be something like this:

```
<script>

var js_markerloc_array= JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($marker_location ); ?>');
var js_markerlat_array= JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($marker_lat ); ?>');
var js_markerlng_array= JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($marker_lng ); ?>');
var markerloc_array = [];
var markerlat_array = [];
var markerlng_array = [];

for (var i=0; len = js_markerloc_array.length; i < len; i++){
    markerloc_array[i] = js_markerloc_array[i];
    markerlat_array[i] = js_markerlat_array[i];
    markerlng_array[i] = js_markerlng_array[i];
}
```

You also need to Parse the Json again on the javascript side once the script executes, it looks confusing but you need to wrap the `php json_encode(x)` in `JSON.parse()` which is Javascripts method for parsing json.

```
i = 0;

while (i < js_markerloc_array.length)
{
    var mapmarker_array = new (google.maps.LatLng(markerlat_array[i],     markerlng_array[i])); //Uses coordinates from database "markers" table
    var test_marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position:mapmarker1, title:         markerloc_array[i]});
    document.write(mapmarker1);
    document.write(markerloc_array[i]);

    i++;
}
</script>
```

I dont know what your are tying to refere to above with mapmarker1, so I cant help you with that, and havent ever used google.maps API before so I cant help any further, but I hope what I have said will help you!!

Comment: Thank you I shall give it a go... and as for the extra three arrays, they are the remnants of some testing I was doing, I'm going to tidy it all up when the rest of it works properly. The general idea is that it loops through the database and populates the map with markers that people have added. Currently it only adds the last marker in the database table, whereas I want it to output all of them. I shall have a look and get back to you... if it works I'll post the full solution so that others can laern from it (annoys me when people don't post up the code when they got it working!!!)

Answer (score 0):

OK, it works! Here is the code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($marker_result)) {

    $marker_location[] = $row["location"];
    $marker_lat[] = $row["lat"];
    $marker_lng[] = $row["lng"];

} //End of while loop

?>

<script>

//Converting php marker arrays to javascript marker arrays for use in for loop
    var js_markerloc_array= <?php echo json_encode($marker_location ); ?>;
    var js_markerlat_array= <?php echo json_encode($marker_lat ); ?>;
    var js_markerlng_array= <?php echo json_encode($marker_lng ); ?>;


    var mapmarkers = [];
    var testmarkers = [];
    i = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < js_markerloc_array.length; i++) {
        mapmarkers[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(js_markerlat_array[i],     js_markerlng_array[i]);
        testmarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: mapmarkers[i],     title: js_markerloc_array[i]});
    }
```

Then further down the page (after the google maps initialise function and options)...

```
    i = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < js_markerloc_array.length; i++) {
    testmarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
```

So, from top to bottom. While loop places database query results into 3 PHP arrays (one for location, one for latitude and one for longitude).
These are then converted to 3 corresponding JavaScript arrays.
Then 2 new JavaScript arrays are created which take their values from the other 3 arrays as shown in the forloop, the 3 arrays are included in googlemaps functions (which was the main thing causing problems before).

Note in this forloop that there is a mapmarkers array which specifies the lat and lng, then a testmarkers array which specifies the position given by the mapmarkers array AND allocates the location name.

It is then the testmarkers array which is called in the forloop further down the page.
This second forloop simply takes the testmarkers array which contains the lat,lng and location and uses the setMap google maps API function to place the marker on the map!

Hence users can now add their own markers to the database, and these can then be added automatically. Hope this helps someone, and thanks for the help and for pointing out my bloated code, constructive criticism very welcome. Thanks again.